# Printing values from two tables with php MSQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've set up two tables on a database at phpmyadmin and I've added content to them through a php-file. The tables look something like this:

**Name:** movies. 
**Columns:** ID, title, directorID (gets the same ID as the director when it gets added to the table thtough a form).

**Name:** director. 
**Columns:** ID(number), name.

What I'm trying to do now is to print (by using SELECT and queries/arrays) a list of all the directors, with the movies they've "directed". Like this:

"director: movie, movie."

"next director: movie."

And so on, until all the directors and their movies have been printed. I've managed to display the list in various orders, using only one table, but I can't seem to get a grip on how to do so values from two. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if I'm unclear, been up a few too many hours trying to work myself around this.

Comment: I thought this was a movie script :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for the query to group all the movie names against the director and then using PHP display them

```
select 
d.ID,
d.name,
group_concat(m.title) as title
from director d
join movies m on m.directorID = d.ID
group by d.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

try this sql

```
SELECT B.name AS director_name, A.title as movie_name
FROM movies A, director B
WHERE A.directorID=B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JOIN` like this

`SELECT * FROM movies LEFT JOIN director ON movies.directorID = director.id` and this will give you the list of all columns from both tables then you can display the one you like by doing this `tablename.column_name`